# Spyder console is showing file path with run file

Tags: python, console, spyder

As I run my program in spyder, I am getting my desired outputs, but in the console, it's showing my whole file pathway with the run file.  How do I get rid of this?
Eg: In[2] runfile('C:/Users/Sara......')

Instead of `In[2] :import numpy as np`

How can I change this setting in the console. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) `runfile` is the command we use to run files in the console. It's equivalent to running `python myfile.py` in a system terminal. If you want to see something printed in the console after running your file, you need to use the `print` function in it. For instance, something like

```
import numpy as np
print('Numpy was imported')
```

However, if you want to see the contents of your file displayed in the console before running them, you need to select them with the mouse and then press the <kbd>F9</kbd> keyboard shortcut or click on the "Run selection" button.